# Backpropagation for each dimension of output in Pytorch

Tags: pytorch, backpropagation

In PyTorch when we call loss.backward() it performs backpropagation for the sample (for stochastic case). Let’s consider my output is 50 dimensional. I have two loss components. First one is an array of dimension 50. How can I run loss.backward() for each dimension separately? I also have another loss component which is a scalar and I want to do normal backpropagation for this one on whole output tensor, together with my first loss on each dimension of the output. Do I have to use a custom loss function?

I have tried x.view() function to split weight matrix to each dimension for the last layer but I have not figured out how to do backpropagation for each dimension yet.

Thanks a lot for you kind help.

Nil

Answer (score 1):

A typical training step looks like this in Pytorch:

```
for input, target in dataset:
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    output = model(input)
    loss = loss_fn(output, target)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

**Change 1:**
Create a custom loss function [[1]](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/custom-loss-functions/29387)

**Change 2:**
Compute and accumulate gradients. Gradients are zeroed out once, then gradients are calculated multiple times based on the number of outputs and finally  `optimizer.step()` is called once.

```
for input, target in dataset:
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    outputs = model(input)

    for output in outputs:
       loss = my_loss_fn(output, target)
       loss.backward()
    
    optimizer.step()
```

The exact implementation will depend on how you compute loss for the vector components.

This assumes that `my_loss_fn()` can be implemented using other Pytorch functions. If that is not the case, you will have to create new Pytorch operations by extending the `Function` class[[2]](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/extending.html).

Comment: Thanks for your response. My loss is a 50 dimensional array. My input and output are also 50 dimensional arrays. So, I want to do backpropagation for each dimension. I tried your code block but I did not work for my case.